# Does full GC imply runFinalization()

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I need to take a clean live object heap dump. I'm currently using the `HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean` to take the heap dump:

```
final String DIAGNOSTIC_MBEAN_NAME = "com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic";
final MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
diagnosticMBean = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(server, DIAGNOSTIC_MBEAN_NAME, HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class);
diagnosticMBean.dumpHeap(fileName, true);
```

This method takes only live objects by invoking a full GC first. However, occasionally, when I analyze the heap dump in YourKit, I notice a lot of unreachable `java.lang.Object` have "Pending Finalization" annotation. I do not want them to be shown in the heap dump.

My question is, should I explicitly call `System.runFinalization()` before `diagnosticMBean.dumpHeap(fileName, true)`, or the full GC already implies that? In the latter case, how do I know if all unreachable objects have been finalized? Sleeping for 10 seconds suffices?

Thanks!

Comment: Both `runFinalization` and `gc` merely "suggest" to the system that it perform the associated action.  Exactly how (and if) finalization is run depends on the specific GC implementation enabled and what parameters are given it.

Comment: I understand `System.gc()` only "suggests". According to my observation, the diagnostic MBean ALWAYS runs full GC. Either this is just coincidence, or the MBean has special code path.

Comment: (No, full GC does not imply that finalization has been run.  In the implementations I used to work with the system did not attempt to run all possible finalizations after every GC but only did a few at a time.  And it took 2-3 GC cycles for finalization to be run on a given object.)

Comment: Do you mean 2-3 full GC or incremental GC cycles?

Comment: I'm not "up" on how incremental vs full is done these days.  It would take more than the simplest incremental, I think.